# how to add new element functions in protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, automated-tests, protractor

we're using protractor/selenium to drive tests - I really want to replace certain functions - like sendkeys and click so that I can a) log what's happening to the console, but b) make them more reliable (we're finding click just randomly fails 10% of the time, so want to put it in a retry loop)

is there an obvious prototype lying around somewhere, or some other object that I can add functions to?  I particularly want to replace the existing functions, but also want to add other helpers, and calling them like

```
element(By.Css("blah")).someHelper()
```

is so much cleaner than

```
someHelper(element( By.Css("blah"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't change protractor at all, you write a wrapper around protractor and use it in your tests.

For example, anytime we want to click an element, we don't use the .click() function, we con't even look up the element. We use our wrapper and call clickElement.

```
resolveSelector: function (selector) {
  var el;
  if (typeof selector === 'string') {
    el = self.getElement(selector);
  } else {
    el = selector;
  }
  return el;
},

getElement: function (selector) {
  verbose('getElement: ' + selector);
  return element(by.css(selector));
},

waitForElement: function (selector) {
  verbose('waitForElement: ' + selector);
  var el = self.resolveSelector(selector);
  return self.wait(function () {
    return self.executeScript(function (el) {
      return el ? $(el).is(':visible') : false;
    }, el.getWebElement()).then(function (val) {
      return val;
    });
  }, 15000, 'Element is not visible. (' + selector + ')');
},

waitForElementClickable: function (selector) {
  verbose('waitForElementClickable: ' + selector);
  var el = self.resolveSelector(selector);
  var condition = function () {
    return self.waitForElement(el).then(function () {
      return self.isElementEnabled(el);
    });
  };
  return self.wait(condition, 15000, 'Element not clickable. (' + selector + ')');
},

clickElement: function (selector) {
  verbose('clickElement: ' + selector);
  var el = self.resolveSelector(selector);
  return self.waitForElementClickable(el).then(function () {
    return el.click();
  });
},
```

You can see that our `clickElement` function does some work, `verbose` is a function that just calls console.log if a config option is set to true.

If you want your tests to be reliable, and be able to tweak things, then you're going to have to write a driver and use it rather than using protractor directly in your tests. This is especially true when a selenium cloud service to run your tests on.

So in our test we call `driver.clickElement('#someID');` or  `driver.clickElement('.someClass');`.

Our driver is big but it has grown over time.